# $P(T\in dt,T\leq C|min(T,C)\geq t)=P(T\in dt|T\geq t)$ for $T,C$ independent

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, independence, fake-proofs

Let $T,C$ be two real valued independent random variables. I want to see the following equality, where $dt$ denotes interval $[t,t+\delta)$ for any $\delta>0$

$P(T\in dt|T\geq t)=P(T\in dt,T\leq C| min(T,C)\geq t)$.

$LHS=\frac{P(T\in dt,T\leq C,T\geq t\cap C\geq t)}{P(T\geq t\cap C\geq t)}$. Denominator can be factorized by $C,T$ independence. Thus it suffices to check numerator $P(T\in dt,T\geq t)=P(T\in dt,T\leq C,T\geq t\cap C\geq t|C\geq t)$. This will show equality.

$P(T\in dt,T\leq C,T\geq t\cap C\geq t|C\geq t)=P(T\in dt,t\leq T\leq C|C\geq t)$

$Q:$ How do I get rid of $T\leq C$ part in above inequality? $C,T$ independence only means for event $a,b$, $P(C\in a,T\in b)=P(C\in a,T\in b)$. $T\leq C$ does not cut either along $C$ or $T$ direction and it cuts in a slanted direction. Have I made a mistake somewhere? If this does not work, how should I argue about equality?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the question. If I take $C\equiv t$ and $T$ uniformly distributed on $[t,t+1]$ for any fixed $t$, then the left-hand side is always positive and the right-hand side always $0$ because $\mathbb{P}(T\leq C) = 0$.

Comment: @Trailblazer I think there is some saddle point here. If I interpret $min(T,C)$ as stopping time and whole expression as conditional expectation over indicator function, the equality should be interpreted as a.s. equality. What you have given is that for a given fixed $t$ the equality fails.